How are network changes propagated across ethereum network?
quick knowledge question:
if ethereum decides to change some parameters of the network, such as;

SECONDS_PER_SLOT
SECONDS_PER_ETH1_BLOCK
ETH1_FOLLOW_DISTANCE

how will these be propagated to the network?
how will everyone else adopt these changes?
will the Ethereum Developers simply shut down their nodes, then change these settings and boot them back up?
How will the changes take place on other participant's machines?

Additional points to @Ougi's answer: the Ethereum blog describes the updates, for example https://blog.ethereum.org/2024/02/27/dencun-mainnet-announcement  At the bottom you can subscribe to get the announcements.

@eth , thanks - i am actually looking to change the parameters in my own private testnet and wanted a better understand of how i would do that. If you have any tips for this, please feel free to mention!

These changes to the protocol rules can be made through a software update to the client software (e.g., Geth, Nethermind). Each node operator can choose whether to upgrade or not. However, if they decide not to update, they risk being part of a minority fork. Major updates usually have a target block number. From this block onwards, the new protocol rules are enforced, giving nodes enough time to prepare for the update.

i thank you for your answer. I have a follow-up to this. How can i do a hard fork of my own? I want to change the aforesaid parameters (SECONDS_PER_SLOT etc) for my network and i think one possible way to do that is to fork the client? Do you have any idea how i can do that?

Why don't you just create your own private network instead of forking the mainnet and set all the parameters to your preferences?

oh i am not forking the mainnet, i am trying to fork my own private testnet and change the parameters to it. That's what i need help with (i.e forking a private testnet, over which i have total control)
